# mina deploy throws error - bundle: command not found ! ERROR: Deploy failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, digital-ocean

Am trying to deploy rails app to digital ocean using mina gem. I did all the configuration and mina setup also is getting executed properly.

mina deploy throws error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the mina deploy --trace

```
root@ruby-rails-1gb-blr1-01:/home/rails/rails-demo# mina deploy --trace
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke remote_environment (first_time)
** Execute remote_environment
** Invoke git:clone (first_time)
** Execute git:clone
** Invoke deploy:link_shared_paths (first_time)
** Execute deploy:link_shared_paths
** Invoke bundle:install (first_time)
** Execute bundle:install
** Invoke rails:db_migrate (first_time)
** Execute rails:db_migrate
** Invoke rails:assets_precompile (first_time)
** Execute rails:assets_precompile
** Invoke deploy:cleanup (first_time)
** Execute deploy:cleanup
** Invoke puma:phased_restart (first_time)
** Invoke remote_environment (first_time)
** Execute remote_environment
** Execute puma:phased_restart
root@139.59.72.156's password: 
-----> Creating a temporary build path
-----> Deploying rails-demo to 139.59.72.156:/home/rails/rails-demo
-----> Fetching new git commits
       remote: Counting objects: 43, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
remote: Total 43 (delta 6), reused 43 (delta 6), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (43/43), done.   
       From github.com:krishnateja/rails-demo
          739096a..4cf74f8  master     -> master
-----> Using git branch 'master'
       Cloning into '.'...
       done.
-----> Using this git commit
       root (4cf74f8):
       > small config change
-----> Symlinking shared paths
-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler
       bash: line 137: bundle: command not found
 !     ERROR: Deploy failed.
-----> Cleaning up build
       Unlinking current
       OK
       Connection to 139.59.72.156 closed.

 !     Run Error
```

**deploy.rb**

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/rvm'
require 'mina/puma'

set :application_name, 'rails-demo'
set :domain, '139.59.72.156'
set :deploy_to, '/home/rails/rails-demo'
set :repository, 'git@github.com:krishnateja/rails-demo.git'

set :shared_dirs, fetch(:shared_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/uploads')
set :shared_files, fetch(:shared_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/puma.rb')
set :user, 'root'

task :environment do
  invoke :'rvm:use', 'ruby-2.2.3'
end

task :setup do
  command %[touch "#{fetch(:shared_path)}/config/database.yml"]
  command %[touch "#{fetch(:shared_path)}/config/secrets.yml"]
  command %[touch "#{fetch(:shared_path)}/config/puma.rb"]
  comment "Be sure to edit '#{fetch(:shared_path)}/config/database.yml', 'secrets.yml' and puma.rb."
end

task :deploy do
  deploy do
    comment "Deploying #{fetch(:application_name)} to #{fetch(:domain)}:#{fetch(:deploy_to)}"
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    on :launch do
      invoke :'puma:phased_restart'
    end
  end

end
```

**puma.rb**

```
environment "production"

bind  "unix:///home/rails/rails-demo/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
pidfile "/home/rails/rails-demo/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "/home/rails/rails-demo/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.state"
directory "/home/rails/rails-demo/current"

workers 2
threads 1,2

daemonize true

activate_control_app 'unix:///home/rails/rails-demo/shared/tmp/sockets/pumactl.sock'

prune_bundler
```

I Some how felt its something to do with the path to executable directory, hence did this.. 
gem environment - gives this.

```
root@ruby-rails-1gb-blr1-01:/home/rails/rails-demo# gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.3 (2015-08-18 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

Added EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY to Path.

```
root@ruby-rails-1gb-blr1-01:/home/rails/rails-demo# export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin
root@ruby-rails-1gb-blr1-01:/home/rails/rails-demo# echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin
```

Comment: I'm a little rusty on this particular set of tools, but looking at the error it appears `Invoke bundle:install (first_time)` needs to also `gem install bundler`, before running `bundle install`.

Comment: Make sure bundle is installed on the server machine. Use command `bundle -v` to make sure it is.

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko Bundler is installed. In the process of configuring mina gem, am able to install all the gems in the vps. When I input the command `mina deploy` it does the tasks as mentioned in the question(above) one by one and one. Am getting the error then. And this is the bunlder version `Bundler version 1.16.0`

Comment: @TomLord This is my deploy.rb file [deploy.rb](https://github.com/krishnateja/rails-demo/blob/master/config/deploy.rb) any idea how can I incorporate gem install bundler near line no.31. I tried this command `%{command gem install bundler}` but no luck.

Comment: @KrishnaTejaKarnam go to `139.59.72.156` by ssh and install bundle in it.

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko Thats not the problem. I did `bundle`, its working fine. When I automate the process with `mina` thats when something is breaking.

Comment: @KrishnaTejaKarnam Maybe it's because you installed bundler under user other than `root` you use in deploy configuration. I believe you have to change ownership of the deploy path to `rails` user and make deployment by this user also. Also make sure that bundler is available for rails user on your server.

Comment: @KrishnaTejaKarnam I guess it's impossible that bundler is available when you connect by ssh to server and unavailable when you do the very same thing by running deploy script. Under the hood it connects via ssh and uses the same environment as when you connect manually.

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko Looks like its a well known issue. I raised a issue on the repo. I will update, if I get any thing.

Comment: @KrishnaTejaKarnam hope you will find more help there!

Answer (score 0):

Bundler has to be installed on your server machine (the one you trying to deploy to). The easiest way is to login into it by ssh and run `gem install bundler` once. It's listed as a common question in [official mina FAQ](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/992ddb7ac655924264a99b68d4a1a6078e4b858c/docs/faq.md#--command-not-found-bundle)

Comment: Buddy you are missing my point. Please check my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well, and workaround it by moving my launch tasks to a separate task. So you could do this by turning

```
task :deploy do
  deploy do
    comment "Deploying #{fetch(:application_name)} to #{fetch(:domain)}:#{fetch(:deploy_to)}"
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    on :launch do
      invoke :'puma:phased_restart'
    end
  end

end
```

to

```
task :deploy do
  deploy do
    comment "Deploying #{fetch(:application_name)} to #{fetch(:domain)}:#{fetch(:deploy_to)}"
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'
  end
end

task :launch do
  invoke :'puma:phased_restart'
end
```

And then execute it separately (which is admittedly suboptimal):

```
$ mina deploy
$ mina launch
```

I don't know the particulars of your task, but I configure mine like so:

```
task :launch => :remote_environment do
  in_path(fetch(:current_path)) do
    invoke :'my:task'
  end
end
```

I know this isn't a solution or explanation, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with rbenv not being loaded.

If you're sure that ruby and bundler are correctly installed on the server as I was then the fix is to make sure the first thing your shell does it to load rbenv.

Open `.bashrc`

Make sure the following **is called before**

`# If not running interactively, don't do anything`

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```